# kubectl get nodes hangs when I delete a node externally

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, rancher

Been experimenting with Kubernetes/Rancher and encountered some unexpected behavior. Today I'm deliberately putting on my [chaos monkey](https://github.com/Netflix/chaosmonkey) hat and learning how things behave when stuff fails.

Here's what I've done:

1) Using the Rancher UI, stand up a 3 node cluster on Digital Ocean [image: DO 3 node cluster]
Success -- a few mins later I have a 3 node cluster, visible in Rancher.

2) Using the Rancher UI, I deleted a node in a 'happy' scenario where I push the appropriate node delete button using Rancher.

Some minutes later, I have a 2 node cluster. Great.
[image: 2 node cluster]

3) Using the **Digital Ocean** admin UI, I delete a node in an 'oops' scenario as if a sysadmin accidentally deleted a node.
[image: delete from DO admin UI]

Back on the ranch (sorry), I click here to view the state of the cluster:
[image: View cluster]

Unfortunately after three minutes, I'm getting a gateway timeout
[image: Gateway timeout]

Detailed timeouts in Chrome network inspector [image: timeouts]

Here's what kubectl says:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
Error from server (Timeout): the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get nodes)
```

So, question is, what happened here?
I was under the impression Kubernetes was 'self healing' and even if this node I deleted was the etcd leader, it would eventually recover. Been around 2 hours -- do I just need to wait more?

Comment: Can you share the info from logs of rancher/rancher container(s), etcd containers, api server?

Comment: Also, did you delete two nodes in total? First one in Rancher UI and the second on in Digitalocean portal?

Comment: Thanks for your reply leodotcloud. I don't seem have access to the Rancher logs right now but I will enquire and see if I can get those.

To your second point, that's correct, I deleted two nodes, one in Rancher UI and the other in Digital Ocean portal as you said.

Comment: In the end, I just deleted this cluster and moved on. I hope to improve my understanding of what happened one day but for now bigger fish to fry